# find if a terms appears in specific pdf sections

Tags: computational-linguistics

i have scientific papers in pdf format and typically contain section. i wanted to know if an input term(s) appear in the introduction/ background or conclusion/ discussion section.

how could this be done using NLP as in parsing techniques? Does machine learning play a role here?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you just use regular expressions for that? Or is there something I'm not getting? :O

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like more of a general programming task than something specific to computational linguistics.